# Some conflicting dependencies were found. Unity Mediation Using Adapters

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, mobile-ad-mediation, ironsource

I recieve the following warning after I install either Admob or IronSource adapters in the mediation configure window:[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Mnj.png)

If I only install the Admob adapter, I only get conflict warnings, but the build still crashes on startup. Unity ads works by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.. I was warned to remove Unity Ads before switching to Mediation, which i did, but the Packages/manifest.json still contained the dependency so removing that fixed everything.